# How to debug if weight keep increasing. Pytorch program

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I m having some doubt when practicing Pytorch program.

I have function like y = m1x1 + m2x2 + c (just 2 weights to learn here). The expected values of weight should be 16,-14 and bias should be 36. But in every epoch the learned wight goes very big. Can any one help me to debug and understand this 20 lines of code, what going wrong here.

```
import torch

x = torch.randint(size = (1,2), high = 10)
w = torch.Tensor([16,-14])
b = 36
#Compute Ground Truth
y = w * x + b

#Find weights by program
epoch = 20
learning_rate = 30

#initialize random
w1 = torch.rand(size= (1,2), requires_grad= True)
b1 = torch.ones(size = [1], requires_grad= True)

for i in range(epoch):
    y1 = w1 * x + b1

    #loss function RMSQ
    loss = torch.sum((y1-y)**2)

    #Find gradient 
    loss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        #update parameters
        w1 -= (learning_rate * w1.grad)
        b1 -= (learning_rate * b1.grad)

        w1.grad.zero_()
        b1.grad.zero_()

    print("B ", b1)  
    print("W ", w1)
```

Thanks,
  Ganesh

Comment: Oops,, sorry, by mistake the learning rate kept to 30. very weird.
However, it is not converging to the original value. I modified to learning_rate value to 0.01  still the parameter not correct even 500 epoch

B  tensor([3.6960], requires_grad=True)
W  tensor([[22.4608, -7.5392]], requires_grad=True)

Comment: Other than the learning rate being astronomical your problem is underconstrained. You have 2 equations (`y1[0]=w1[0]*x[0] + b1` and `y1[1]=w1[1]*x[1] + b1`) with 3 unknowns (`w1[0]`, `w1[1]`, and `b1`). Because of your objective function you should expect `y1` to get closer to `y` but you shouldn't expect `w1` and `b1` to converge to `w` and `b` necessarily.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I got that point. @jo

Answer (score 1):

You have a very large learning rate.

This is an illustration from [Jeremy Jordan's blog](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/) that explains exactly what is going on in your case.

[image]